# Storing public certificates and private keys safely

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I want to use `certificate based authentication in AWS Lambda to generate oauth tokens.` Currently I am storing the `certificates and private keys` locally and running it like a normal java application.

I am planning to use `AWS Secrets manager` to store these certificates and keys. However the issue is since we are using `terraform` to provision `AWS` resources, it seems like we will have to keep these certs and keys in our `bitbucket` repo which will have security risks. Is there any other way I can use these certificates in `AWS lambda` without actually storing them in `bitbucket` repo?

Comment: "However the issue is since we are using terraform to provision AWS resources, it seems like we will have to keep these certs and keys in our bitbucket repo which will have security risks." Please elaborate on why you think this is the case. That is certainly not a requirement of Terraform.

Comment: In case of provisioning AWS secrets using terraform, you need to specify the key and value for the secret in the .tf file itself right? As per https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/secretsmanager_secret_version Otherwise how will I be able to add the secrets into AWS? Is there any other way?

Comment: You don't need to automate everything. You can create the Secret in Terraform, and then manually store the actual secret in it. Certificate management isn't a good candidate for automation, since it involves steps such as signing a CSR.

Answer (score 1):

The Terraform `aws_secretsmanager_secret_version` resource takes a string value, but that doesn't mean you have to hard-code the string inside that resource. You need to think about how you can read that key value into Terraform and reference it inside the resource.

For example, that string could come from a [local file](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/file), or an [S3 object](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_bucket_object). Terraform could also [generate the TLS key](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tls/latest/docs/resources/private_key) for you.

Comment: Is it a good idea to create secrets by Terraform? Can you share your idea?

Comment: "that string could come from a local file, or an S3 object", you mean to say the string value can be stored as an S3 object right? Then isn't it same as storing the key itself in the S3 object? Doesn't that defeat our main goal of having key in the secrets manager?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. I've worked on systems that had a CI/CD environment in one AWS account, and deployed into another AWS account, and we would store some things like that in S3 in the first account, so they would be available to the CI/CD pipeline. I'm just throwing out examples to let you know that Terraform can read that string value from many different places, it isn't required to hard-code the value in the Terraform template.